# Jupyter: Triggering an output when clicking on a point in a scatterplot which replaces previous outputs (rather than being appended)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, plotly, seaborn

I'm trying to build an interactive scatter plot in Jupyter, where clicking on a point will trigger plotting another (non interactive) Seaborn plot based on the point clicked. Iv'e managed to do this using plotly (This is a toy example)

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns; sns.set()
import numpy as np
%matplotlib inline

x = np.arange(10)
f = go.FigureWidget([go.Scatter(x=x, y=2*x)])

scatter = f.data[0]
f.layout.hovermode = 'closest'

# create our callback function
def click_callback(trace, points, selector):
    sns.lineplot(np.arange(10), [points.ys[0]]*10)
    plt.show()

scatter.on_click(click_callback)

f
```

The problem is that each new Seaborn plot is appended to the cell while I want it to replace the previous one. If I try to use IPython.display.clear_output(), the original plotly scatterplot is erased too. How can I clear only the Seaborn plot before plotting a new one?

Also, if there is a easy to implement superior solution for the general task (Triggering a new plot when clicking on a point in the scatter plot), I'd like to know

Thanks!